# Javascript / if, else

Tags: javascript, html

Need help with my code. Do not understand why it does not work properly.
Description:
Create a web page with a linked external script that takes as input the user age. if the age is less than 18 the web page should display "You are too young to vote" Otherwise the web page should proceed by asking if the person did register to vote or not using a prompt. If No the page should display:" You need to register before you can vote" if yes the program display: " You can vote"
Use descriptive names of variables, appropriate primary and secondary conditions ( if/else), and display correctly the outputs on the webpage based on the condition.

```html
<head>
    <title> Voting! </title>
    
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var age = prompt("Please enter your age");
    if (age < 18) {
        document.write("You are too young to vote!");
    } else if (age >= 18) {
        alert("You are eligible to vote!");
    }
    var answare = prompt("Did you register to vote?");
    if (answare == 'yes') {
        document.write("You can vote!");
    } else {
        document.write("You need to register before you can vote");

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `var age = +prompt("Please enter your age");` - so now age is a Number not a String

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Is it that it keeps asking `Did you register to vote?` after determining that the user is too young? Well, you’re not preventing your code from doing so. You can nest `if` statements.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

Not an optimal solution but will give you an idea why it still ask if the user is registered or not even if the user is too young.

```js
var age = prompt("Please enter your age");
if (age < 18) {
  document.write("You are too young to vote!");

} else if (age >= 18) { 
  //wrap inside so this will only be called if the age is 18 or above
  alert("You are eligible to vote!");
  var answare = prompt("Did you register to vote?");
  if (answare == 'yes') {
    document.write("You can vote!");
  } else {
    document.write("You need to register before you can vote");

  }
}
```